# Export to PDF from data source in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I am trying to implement "Export to PDF" module in asp.net. There are no errors, no exceptions but still unable to generate PDF document. Tried solutions from stackoverflow but no help.
Here's my code sample...
 also applied EnableEventValidation="false" in <%@page> tag**

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnExportTOPDF" Text="Export to PDF" runat="server" Style="color: white" CssClass="form-control btn-danger rcolr"
    OnClick="btnExportTOPDF_Click" /> 


    //Code Behind
    public DataTable bindUserData()
        {
            DataTable DtUser = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bindUSermaster", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(DtUser);
            gvuser.DataSource = DtUser;
            gvuser.DataBind();

            return DtUser;
        }


     protected void btnExportTOPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportBindPDF();
        }

     public void ExportBindPDF()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        //To Export all pages
                        gvuser.AllowPaging = false;
                        this.bindUserData();

                        gvuser.RenderControl(hw);
                        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();
                        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                        pdfDoc.Close();

                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
                        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                        //Response.End();
                        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

**Please help.**

Comment: Why are you unable? What does all this code do instead?

Comment: The code executes till end without any exception but the pdf report is not generated.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: For Debuging I have try by using VS2010 Debugger line by line using breakpoint. there is no error but still i m unable to create a pdf file for the document.

Comment: Do you mean that a PDF document is not created on the server? Or a document is correct, but the file is not downloaded?

Comment: @Vladimir we are not sure about this. as per my code i have i was trying to create a pdf file from gridview which is created using datasource but i have no result with no exception. please help